# Derivative of modulus

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If

$$x=\ln\left|y+\sqrt{y^{2}+1}\right|$$

Is there a way to obtain $y$ in terms of $x$ in Mathematica?

How to find dx/dy in Mathematica?
I tried:
D[x,y] in mathematica. But the answer I got is:

$$\frac{sgn\left(\phi+\sqrt{\phi^{2}+1}\right)\left|\phi+\sqrt{\phi^{2}+1}\right|'}{\sqrt{\phi^{2}+1}}$$

Why there is a $'$ in the the modulus again. I think it means we need to  find derivative again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

x = Log[Abs[y + Sqrt[y^2 + 1]]];
```

If `y` is real then

```
Assuming[Element[y, Reals], D[x, y] // FullSimplify]

(* 1/Sqrt[1 + y^2] *)
```

or

```
D[x /. Abs[z_] :> Sqrt[z^2], y] // Simplify

(* 1/Sqrt[1 + y^2] *)
```

or

```
D[x /. Abs :> RealAbs, y] // Simplify

(* 1/Sqrt[1 + y^2] *)

% === %% === %%%

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** To obtain `y` in terms of `x`

Clear["Global`*"]

```
eqn = x == Log[Abs[y + Sqrt[y^2 + 1]]];

sol = Solve[eqn, y, Reals]

(* {{y -> 1/2 E^-x (-1 + E^(2 x))}} *)

% // FullSimplify

(* {{y -> Sinh[x]}} *)

eqn /. sol[[1]] // Simplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

As a function of a complex argument Abs is not differentiable. E.g. for z=x+I y:

```
(Abs[z0+dx]-Abs[0])/dx -> 1
(Abs[z0+I dy]-Abs[0])/(I dy) -> - I
```

Therefore, the limit depends on the direction. However, if you restrict the argument to be real, then you can use FullSimplify to get the derivative of Abs:

```
FullSimplify[D[Abs[x], x], x \[Element] Reals]
(* Sign[x] *)
```